# Why setting the value of a column in pandas is not working>

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here][1]I have a data frame named election and I want to find set the winner column as NaN for rows where the margin is less than 1

![enter image description here][2]

I am doing something like this

```
too_close = election['margin']<1

election.loc[too_close, 'winner'] = np.nan # THIS IS WORKING
```

My question is since `election.loc[too_close, 'winner']` and  `election[too_close].winner` both return pandas series. Why setting the column value using latter doesn't work and the former works. I am new to pandas. Here is the data frame's 5 initial values

```
          state   total      Obama     Romney  winner  voters    turnout     margin
county                                                                             
Adams        PA   41973  35.482334  63.112001  Romney   61156  68.632677  27.629667
Allegheny    PA  614671  56.640219  42.185820   Obama  924351  66.497575  14.454399
Armstrong    PA   28322  30.696985  67.901278  Romney   42147  67.198140  37.204293
Beaver       PA   80015  46.032619  52.637630  Romney  115157  69.483401   6.605012
Bedford      PA   21444  22.057452  76.986570  Romney   32189  66.619031  54.929118
```

Comment: Your image link seems broken. Can you fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas separates between *getting*  and *setting* (ie, changing) methods. Since setting modifies your original dataframe, Pandas wants to be more cautious about how you do it. `loc` is the official way to do this. Syntax like `election[too_close].winner` is simply a shortcut (or "sugar") for *getting*, but doesn't allow you to *set*.

Comment: Thanks!! Makes sense. So .loc is the only way to set the values?

Comment: Not exactly the only way - have a look at [this guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html#Setting)